# Domain Controller Adds Unwanted DNS entries

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system

I have a Windows Server 2003 Domain Controller, that I will call FOO.  FOO's internal IP was recently changed from 10.20.0.1 to 10.50.0.1 .

This change has caused **two extra DNS entries to exist for FOO besides the correct one**: 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.163.1 .  These subnets don't even exist on my network.  When I try to delete them from DNS on every domain controller they just come back.

How do I get rid of these DNS entries so they do not come back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have any VMware products installed on FOO? It looks to me like you might have IPs for VMware virtual NICs being registered in the DNS.

Edit:

Sure thing. By default these NICs don't have TCP/IP bound to them. It sounds like you've got TCP/IP bound to two of them. Head into the "Network Settings" on the host OS. In the TCP/IP properties on each interface, go into the "Advanced" settings and uncheck the "Register this connection in DNS" checkbox on the DNS tab.

If you're running a DNS server on that machine too, alter the "Listen on:" setting on the "Interfaces" tab of the properties of that server in "DNS Management" to include only the IP address you want it to register / listen on for DNS.

Comment: Right on, there a work around to keep these interfaces from being populated into DNS?

Comment: Rather than comment, I edited my posting. Glad to see my psychic powers paid off again... *smile*

Answer (score 1):

your DC FOO have only one LAN interface?